# Refactoring code in terms of cpu cycles JAVA

Tags: java

Question:i just want to ask 2 question, if i write 2 below codes in java then which one is faster in terms of cpu cycles and why? Someone told me that 1st option is not correct in terms of cpu cycle because in that 2 conditions are checked i.e if and !

```
boolean flag = true;

//OPTION ONE
if(!flag) {
  //error
} else {
  //got the answer
}

//OPTION TWO
if(flag) {
  //got the answer
} else {
  //error
}
```

Comment: Do you have *any* reason to believe that whatever difference there might be (which is likely to depend on a huge number of factors) will be significant in your application? Write code whichever way is *cleanest*, and leave micro-optimization until you've proved you need to.

Comment: but i want to know the correct answer

Comment: There is no one definitive correct answer. It depends on exactly what VM you're using and what optimization level the JIT is performing at the time (amongst other things).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is **no practical difference** on a modern JVM implementation.

The compiler will do the right thing, don't worry about it. In fact, if it can prove that flag always has a constant value of true at compile time it will eliminate the check and the unreachable branch entirely.

Comment: what if the boolean flag value comes from server or came in runtime

Comment: Then it still won't make a difference.  Stop optimizing things like this.